# Converting a rails 2 count calculation to rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I am attempting to convert this rails 2 count calculation to rails 3 but I'm having some issues

```
answers.count('user_agents.browser', :joins => :user_agent, :group => 'user_agents.browser', :order => 'COUNT(user_agents.browser) DESC')
```

That is from rails 2 and gives me an error of

```
PGError: ERROR:  column answers.user_agents.browser does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT     COUNT("answers"."user_agents.browser") AS "count_...
                         ^
: SELECT     COUNT("answers"."user_agents.browser") AS "count_user_agents_browser", user_agents.browser AS user_agents_browser FROM       "answers"  INNER JOIN "user_agents" ON "user_agents"."id" = "answers"."user_agent_id" WHERE     (answers.survey_id = 18) GROUP BY  user_agents.browser ORDER BY  COUNT(user_agents.browser) DESC
```

I've tried converting myself, this is as close as I have gotten

```
answers.select('COUNT(user_agents.browser)').joins(:user_agent).group('user_agents.browser').order('COUNT(user_agents.browser) DESC')
```

But that still doesn't work and gives me this error

```
undefined method `keys' for [#<Answer >, #<Answer >, #<Answer >]:ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Some background, I am getting an array of answers from my question model that has_many Answers.  Answers also belongs to the UserAgent model which has_many Answers.  My end goal is to take an array of answers and figure out how many came from each UserAgent.  This code work in rails 2.  I am using Postgresql for the db.

Comment: Can you try using the `to_sql` method to see the actual sql. For example `puts answers.select('COUNT(user_agents.browser)').joins(:user_agent).group('user_agents.browser').order('COUNT(user_agents.browser) DESC').to_sql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out, and in fact I do think it makes a whole lot more sense

```
UserAgent.group(:browser).joins(:answers).merge(answers).count(:browser)
```

Merge is pretty damn awesome